# Python changing order of a list when I change the formatting

Tags: python, list, format, integer, decimal

I am trying to change the format of all items in my list from float to integer. My code seem to do the job, however it is changing the order of the items in the list.

A reproducible example:

```
l = [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
[int(f'{float(l[int(i)]):g}') for i in l]

>>> Out: [1, -1, 0]
```

Any idea how to avoid the re-arrangement of these elements?

Thank you.

Comment: its because your are indexing the list using the values,  with ```l[int(i)]```

Comment: Why not just use `[int(i) for i in l]`?

Comment: ```i``` doesn't return ```0,1,2``` it returns ```-1,0,1``` hence you would have ```1,-1,0``` in your list

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I am writing a generic script that applies to many cases. It has been a while since I accessed this script and forgot why I added this complexity. Can you think of any case where the simple solution of map/basic list comprehension won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`l[int(i)])` <- you're accessing the list positions by index here. Just re-write your code using map:

```
l = [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
o = list(map(int, l))
print(o)
```

Output:

```
[-1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking this, simply do:

```
l = [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
[int(i) for i in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use both comprehension list and functional programming:

```
l = [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
result1 = [int(i) for i in l]
result2 = list(map(int, l))
```